# Iterator Method for Binary Tree in C

Tags: c, function, tree, iterator, binary-tree

I have been given the following code to make an iterator method to use on a binary tree in C. That is to apply a function to every value in the binary tree.

`int bst_char_iterate(bst_char *t, char (*fun)(char item))`

"Bst_char *t" equating to a pointer to the tree, "*fun" equating to a pointer to a function call and "item" being the value of which the function is called upon.

I thought iterators should really be done as void functions, so I am lost as to how to approach this.

Please help!

Edit: The instruction I got was the following:

> Add a new method to the library that applies a function to every value
>   in the tree. (This is an iterator method for trees.)
>
> int bst_char_iterate(bst_char *t, char (*fun)(char item))
>
> NB: The BST property will only be preserved by this method if the
>   function passed to it is monotonic. A function f is monotonic whenever
>
> x <= y (arrow) f(x) <= f(y).

Edit 2: The following has not worked for me:

```
int bst_char_iterate(bst_char *t, char (*fun)(char item)) {
    assert(t!=NULL);
    struct node * p = t->root;
    if (p!=NULL) {
       p->item = fun(p->item);
       p->left->item = bst_char_iterate(t,fun(p->left));
       p->right->item = bst_char_iterate(t,fun(p->right));
    } else {
       return 0;
    }
}
```

With quite a few errors. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by "iterators should really be done as void functions".  This looks like you should just do an in-order traversal of the bst and `node->item = fun(node->item)` at each node.

Comment: Have you been given any guidance on what to do with the return value of `*fun` or what your function should ultimately return as an `int` ?

Answer (score 3):

You say you want an "iterator" method, but then you describe that as "to apply a function to every value in the tree", which is an "apply" method, not an "iterator" method.  An iterator method generally takes a reference to some element of a data structure and returns a reference to the next element (or modifies the reference in place to refer to the next element).  So do you want an actual iterate method, or do you want an apply method that you're going to call "iterate" thus confusing all future readers of your code?

If the latter, you want a function that traverses your tree, calling the function for every value.  A simple recursive traversal should do the trick:

```
void bst_char_apply(bst_char *t, void (*fun)(char item)) {
    if (t->left) bst_char_apply(t->left, fun);
    fun(t->value);
    if (t->right) bst_char_apply(t->right, fun);
}
```

Comment: That's not so much depth-first as in-order, isn't it? I guess post-order would be 'depth-first' (go downwards before doing the current level).

Comment: Yeah, not really depth first.  Just recursive.

Comment: Surely I can just make that into an integer function by adding a `return t->value;` to it?

Comment: @user3155247: Not usefully -- that just returns the value in the root node.  If you must have an int return type, might as well just add `return 0;`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably return the next BST item after the given item. Then the function can be called again with the newly returned item, and it should return the item after that, and so on, until you reach the end.

So you need a special value to indicate that there isn't another item left; maybe 0?